# sending data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a side menu, when the side menu is pressed. It should take the `SharedPreferences` `String` and send it to the `Fragment`. And the `Fragment` should set the `TextView` and it will be displayed on the `MainActivity`.

The sent data to fragment is not showing up in the `MainActivity`,I am getting the error. Any solutions?

Main Activity code (when option pressed):-

```
if(num == 0)
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = sp.getString("username", "DEFAULT");
        FragmentOne F1 = new FragmentOne();

        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        FT.add(R.id.relative_main, F1);
        F1.setTextV(username);
        FT.commit();

    }
```

Fragment

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    textV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_one_textview);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    return v;
}

public void setTextV(String username)
{
    textV.setText(username);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't need to send data to the fragment because in a fragment you can access to SharedPreferences.

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_one_textview);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = sp.getString("username", "DEFAULT");
        textV.setText(username);

        return v;
    }
```

For other cases, the best way to send information from the Activity to the Fragment is using a Bundle.

```
if(num == 0)
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = sp.getString("username", "DEFAULT");
        FragmentOne F1 = new FragmentOne();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("username", username);
        // You can add all the information that you need in the same bundle

        F1.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        FT.add(R.id.relative_main, F1);
        FT.commit();

    }
```

Fragment:-

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_one_textview);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        textV.setText(getArguments().getString("username", ""));

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: What error? Attach the stacktrace or something if you want some help

Answer (score 1):

Following issue is in current implementation :

**1.**  If `fragment_one` is in layout which return in from `onCreateView` then use `v` to call findViewById :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
textV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_one_textview);
return v;
```

**2.** Call `setTextV` after `FT.commit();` :

```
    FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
    FT.add(R.id.relative_main, F1);
    FT.commit();
    F1.setTextV(username);
```

Because you are getting value from `SharedPreferences` to show in TextView so get value from Preferences in `onCreateView` and show in TextView.

Comment: I tried updating the `Fragment` with `v.findViewById(R.id.frag_one_textview)` and initialized the `setTextV` after `FT.commit();` still it showing the error.