# Select image and sent the result to another activity in android studio keep force closing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bitmap, uri

So, i got a problem where everytime i choose an image the app will do force close and of course the choosen image failed to sent to another activity, But for camera activity its doing fine.
This is my code

**ChooseActivity.kt**

```
 private fun takePhoto() {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
  }

  private fun chooseLibrary() {
    val libraryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(libraryIntent, LIBRARY_REQUEST)
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return

    when (requestCode) {
      CAMERA_REQUEST -> {
        val thumbnail: Bitmap = data!!.getParcelableExtra("data")
        val intent = Intent(this@ChooseActivity, StillImageActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("bitmap", thumbnail)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
      }
      LIBRARY_REQUEST -> {
        val uri: Uri = data!!.getData()!!
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, uri)
        val intent = Intent(this@ChooseActivity, StillImageActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
      }
    }
  }

  companion object {
    private const val CAMERA_REQUEST = 10
    private const val LIBRARY_REQUEST = 20
  }
}
```

Originally, i use code from CAMERA_REQUEST for LIBRARY_REQUEST except for variable, but it doesn't work, so i decided to look for any fix, and still no luck

and i use this code to receive the result in another activity

**StillImageActivity.kt**

```
fun getImage() {
    val extras = intent.extras
    if (extras != null) {
      val bitmap = extras["bitmap"] as Bitmap
      if (bitmap != null) {
        imagePreview?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

        classifyImage(bitmap)
      }
    }
  }
```

i make it as a function because i wanted to call it here so the image will be classified. This is an image classification apps

```
// Setup image classifier.
    try {
      classifier = ImageClassifier(this)
    } catch (e: FirebaseMLException) {
      textView?.text = getString(R.string.fail_to_initialize_img_classifier)
    }

    // Classify the sent image
    getImage()
  }
```

any possible fix for this problem? i wanted the choosen image from gallery is received using this function so it will be immediately classified just like the camera activity, or if there are any better solution it will help a lot.

This is the logcat error

```
2020-08-05 17:24:42.425 27490-27490/com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1639092)
2020-08-05 17:24:42.429 27490-27490/com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-08-05 17:24:42.435 27490-27490/com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl, PID: 27490
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=20, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/3724/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/1941833173 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F3724/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1941833173} }} to activity {com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl/com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl.ChooseActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1718)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5210)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5168)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5539)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5507)
        at com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl.ChooseActivity.onActivityResult(ChooseActivity.kt:60)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1639092 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:511)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3847)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1712)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5210) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767) 
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5168) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754) 
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5539) 
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5507) 
        at com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl.ChooseActivity.onActivityResult(ChooseActivity.kt:60) 
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8131) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-08-05 17:24:42.460 27490-27490/com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit.automl I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27490 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is the error? show the logcat please

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch an exception. Find out which one. The logcat will tell you all.

Comment: this is the logcat https://pastebin.com/sELTFh1P
any help? i don't know what to do, also i'm not sure if the code for the LIBRARY_REQUEST is the right one

Comment: Ideally, have just one activity, not two. If for some reason you absolutely must have two activities, pass the `Uri`, not the `Bitmap`, between them. You will need to do that using `setData()` on the `Intent`, along with `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`, so the receiving activity not only gets the `Uri` but the permissions to work with its content.

Comment: but if i pass the `Uri` won't it be unreadable for my `getImage` function? since it's only take `bitmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`

This can happen when you pass around too much data.

You could use static fields or singletons to share data between activities, please see: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3 - Another way, which goes out of the scope of this question but can easily be found by searching here on SO is by passing the data using SharedPreferences, e.g.: [sending data from activity to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504826/sending-data-from-activity-to-fragment)

There is a tool you can use to find out where this is happening called:
https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool

In the activity where this error happens, you should add `outState.clear();`

e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Clear the Activity's bundle
    outState.clear();
}
```

Comment: Hey it works, but only for very-low sized image tho, is there any way to make it work with normal size image too?

Comment: Did you look into the sharedpreferences api? :)